# Sound recording anonymization

Tags: discrete-signals, speech-processing

I want to study stress based on sound recordings. However, there are many concerns about keeping the identity of the recorded persons anonymous.

I want to keep intensity and spectral contents intact but I am not interested in the message or the identity of speakers.

I thought about time reversing the recordings, but this could be easily undone by someone.

Do you have any suggestions for this purpose?

Comment: You write that intensity and spectral content should remain intact. Would it therefore be sufficient to only store, say, an estimate of the power spectral density (PSD) of the recording and discard the time-domain signal. There is no way to obtain the time-domain signal from the PSD estimate.

Comment: Spectral content can provide some information about stress but there non-spectral metrics/features that are also useful. Jitter and shimmer for example.

Comment: Adding to my first comment: couldn't you just compute and store the features that you need for your analysis and discard the original recordings, then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think there's one:

You seem to be in the process of figuring out what about a piece of audio signifies stress.
As long as you don't know that, you can't erase any identifying information from it without standing a high probability of also erasing your "stress" information.